# What does (6, 0, do in Open ERP 7 code?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm wondering what does `(6, 0,` do in following code, maybe some filtering taxes? I understand other parts.  It's snippet from account_invoice class. Of course I know it's tulpe. Just wondering why Open erp use **6** not **4**. What is special about number **6**? By the way I'm not trying to add something to context.

```
  self.pool.get('account.invoice.line').create(cr, uid, {
    'invoice_id':inv_id,
    'name': line.product_id.name_template,
    'account_id': line.product_id.categ_id.property_account_expense_categ.id,
    'price_unit': line.price_unit or 0.0,
    'quantity': line.product_qty,
    'product_id': line.product_id.id,
    'uos_id': line.product_uom.id,
    'invoice_line_tax_id': [(6, 0, [x.id for x in line.taxes_id])],
    }, context=context)
```

Comment: Are you going to add some context?

Comment: Wow, you're asking us what a random meaningless number does in some completely undefined context in code we can't see? Uhm… *shrug*

Comment: Klaus' question about context means: **please tell us more about where this line of code occurs.** We cannot tell you anything about a number **6** with the given information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(6, 0, [IDs])` replace the list of linked IDs.

Example:

```
[(6, 0, [8, 5, 6, 4])] sets the many2many to ids [8, 5, 6, 4]
```

Here are other codes:

`(0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
(1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
(2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
(3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
(4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
(5)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
(6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)`

Comment: Thanks you. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

See [ORM](https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods/) for 6 and 7 versions doc. At the end of the page you will find m2m and o2m semantic (this one is m2m)